# Parse HTTParty response - something weird is happening

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, httparty

I'm trying to parse a json response and thought what i had was working. Well, it is but it's also doing something a bit odd.

Here is my method in my controller:

```
def other_properties

    @response = HTTParty.get("http://api.nestoria.co.uk/api?place_name=ch66&action=search_listings&pretty=1&encoding=json&listing_type=rent&country=uk")

    @data = @response['response']['listings']

    respond_to do |format|

      format.js
    end  

end
```

I have this in the view:

```
<%= @data.each do |item| %>

 <%= image_tag(item['img_url']) %>

<% end %>
```

This correctly displays the images but ALSO displays the rest of the response held in the `@data` variable. What the heck is going on!

Can anyone see what's going on?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was late and i was tired. Realised i needed to use `map` rather than `each`.

```
<%= @data.map do |item| %>

 <%= image_tag(item['img_url']) %>

<% end %>
```

This solved my issue.

Cheers